# How to query from maximum number all the way down in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo collection which stores orders for a shopping site. Therefore, it starts from 0 and goes up 1 by 1. I want to search for documents, 10 each time, but starting from the max order number all the way down to 0.

In order to do this, I had the idea of getting the max order number and then simply query for the order number from max-10 to max.

Is there a better way to do this? And also, how do I get the maximum order number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation query to achieve this

```
var limit = 10;
var offset = page_no > 1 ? (page_no-1) * limit : 0;


Orders.aggregate([
    {
        $sort:{
            'order_no':-1
        }
    },{
        $skip:offset
    },{
        $limit:limit
    }
])
```

Here `order_no` is the `Number` type in your schema as you mentioned & `offset` will be set based on the `page_no` you increase from `1-N`